# matplotlib cannot find configuration file matplotlibrc

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, configuration

I am using matplotlib 1.3.1 with python 3.4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I would like to use a [matplotlibrc configuration file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) in `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. However it seems like matplotlib is unable to find it:

```
~$ ls ~/.config/matplotlib/
matplotlibrc
~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:766: UserWarning: Could not find matplotlibrc; using defaults
  warnings.warn('Could not find matplotlibrc; using defaults')
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:882: UserWarning: could not find rc file; returning defaults
  warnings.warn(message)
```

The content of my `matplotlibrc` is the default one from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

How can I make matplotlib find the configuration file?

EDIT:

```
>>> matplotlib.get_configdir()
'/home/<me>/.matplotlib'
```

Comment: What do you get from `matplotlib.get_configdir()`?

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to read ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc? `chmod u+rwx ~/.config/matplotlib` and `chmod u+r ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` might help.

Comment: @Marius see my edit to the question.

Comment: OK, so it looks like you should be putting the matplotlibrc file in `~/.matplotlib` rather than `~/.config/matplotlib` then. Not sure why the config path would have changed.

Comment: @Marius But when I do that I get the message `UserWarning: Found matplotlib configuration in ~/.matplotlib/. To conform with the XDG base directory standard, this configuration location has been deprecated on Linux, and the new location is now '/home/me/.config'/matplotlib/. Please move your configuration there to ensure that matplotlib will continue to find it in the future.`
So I'd like to use the correct location, or at least get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docstring of `matplotlib.get_configdir()` I discovered that matplotlib will not look in `~/.config` if `.matplotlib/` exists.

So even though `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` exists, you should delete the `~/.matplotlib` directory entirely.

Note that I also had to [delete matplotlib's fontcache](https://askubuntu.com/a/578130) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I found mine here without having to delete the .matplotlib dir

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc